# Compile Typescript to Javascript and access from a html file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I've been building a library on top of Typescript. A set of model classes that compose my library.
So, after that, I've used webpack to compile the TS code, and create a simple xxxx.js library inside `dist` folder.

The problem is that I don't know how to expose nor a method or a class outside.

This is my `index.ts` file.

```
import Whatever from "./Whatever";

/**
 * Create new Whatever instance
 *
 * @return {Whatever}
 */
exports = function() {
    return Whatever.create();
};
```

And that would be my webpack config file.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') + '/index.ts',
    output: {
        filename: 'whatever.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json' ]
    }
};
```

There is something I'm doing wrong, because in a simple html file I'm doing as an example, and after including the created file as a script, I'm not able to locate the generated instance.

Anyone with some light, please?

Comment: Why don't you use ES6 export syntax in the index.ts file?

Comment: @Bergi what would be this format?

Comment: `export default function() { return Whatever.create() }` or `export function createWhatever() { return Whatever.create() }`

Comment: @Bergi and once is compiled, and the whatever.js file is generated, how I'm suposed to access this value?

Comment: Oops, wrong link above (in deleted comment). I meant https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget

Comment: @Bergi I was actually looking at that :) Thanks so much!